# XML conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert XML using XSLT. Below is the structure of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetInvoiceList>
<Request>
<BillStatusCode typecode="1">type description</BillStatusCode>
<EBillProcessStatusCode typecode="2">type description</EBillProcessStatusCode>
</Request>
</GetInvoiceList>
```

I tried this XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<GetInvoiceList>
<GetInvoiceList>
    <Request>
        <Request>
            <BillStatusCode>
                <BillStatusCode>type description</BillStatusCode>
                <typecode>1</typecode>
            </BillStatusCode>
            <EBillProcessStatusCode>
                <EBillProcessStatusCode>type description</EBillProcessStatusCode>
                <typecode>2</typecode>
            </EBillProcessStatusCode>
        </Request>
    </Request>
</GetInvoiceList>
</GetInvoiceList>
```

Expected Output:

```
  <GetInvoiceList>
       <Request>
                <BillStatusCode>
                <BillStatusCode>type description</BillStatusCode>
                <typecode>1</typecode>
            </BillStatusCode>
            <EBillProcessStatusCode>
                <EBillProcessStatusCode>type description</EBillProcessStatusCode>
                <typecode>2</typecode>
            </EBillProcessStatusCode>
        </Request>
        </GetInvoiceList>
```

The code is working on all nodes that is why duplicates nodes got created. I want it to work on only those nodes which are having text & attributes.

Would appreciate any help regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output you are actually expecting in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my ques now. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `node()` matching template; you have both an `xsl:copy` and an `xsl:element`, which both create the same element, resulting in the duplicate. This applies to all nodes

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:element name="{name()}">
```

What you need is to change this to only match elements with attributes

```
<xsl:template match="*[@*]">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you have a template matching just `node()` in which you remove the `xsl:element` element

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Right. Duplicate values are not there now, but it has changed the desired output also. <BillStatusCode> is not having seperate closing tag now.